# How to make image responsive and auto scale down the height

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I have two unequal responsive columns, the smaller one on the right is text and the bigger one on the left is an image. When I resize the browser window to see how the columns fit the page, it works fine until it gets to the max width 700px and the column stack onto of each other. The bottom column is fine however the top one (image) doesn't show the full image only a tiny strip going along the width of the page. how can I get it to auto adjust the height to show the full image?

I have tried setting height on the left column as auto but that didn't work and it continued to only show a small strip.

```css
.column {
      float: left;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 300px;
  
  
    }

    .left {
      width: 60%;
      background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/k5gf0zz.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;

    }

    .right {
      width: 40%;
    }

    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
     content: "";
     display: table;
     clear: both;
    }


    /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .column {
        width: 100%;
      }
     
 
    }
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column left";>
    
  
      </div>
      <div class="column right" style="background-color:#FDE4EC;">
      <center> <p><font size="8">We Provide Quality Skin Care</font></p>
     <p style = "font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">Let us help you feel beautiful!</p> 
 
     <br> 
 
     <button class="button2"><b>BOOK NOW</b></button> </center>

  
  
       </div>
    </div>


    </body>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! To make it easier for people to understand your problem can you provide a more complete example including HTML? Ideally as a snippet.

Comment: Done, i added the html

Comment: This seems constrained by columns height, that is fixed to 300px

Comment: Note that the `<center>` and `<font>` elements have been obsolete for a number of years and should not be used anymore. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: without the column height fixed to 300px the image is a thin strip before they even stack on top of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:none;
}
.left {
  width: 60%;
background:url("http://i.imgur.com/k5gf0zz.jpg") no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
}


.right {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  img{
    display:block;
  }
  .left {
  background:none;

  }

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left";>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/k5gf0zz.jpg">

  </div>
  <div class="column right" style="background-color:#FDE4EC;">
  <center> <p><font size="8">We Provide Quality Skin Care</font></p>
 <p style = "font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">Let us help you feel beautiful!</p> 

 <br> 

 <button class="button2"><b>BOOK NOW</b></button> </center>



   </div>
</div>
```

try adding img to your html with `max-width:100%` and  `height:auto` for small screens and div with `background` for large screens!

Comment: add `img` tag to your html and remove it as background!

Comment: ah that worked for when they stack on top each other but now they don't unstack when the browser is big enough

Comment: check edit post now this will work or check this JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/2g1nway3/12/

Comment: thank you, may i ask how to make the image width reduce to match up the height with the column on the right before they stack on top of each other as before they stacked on top of each other both columns were the same height as the image width would reduce as the screen reduces to match up with the other column but now the width of the image is always 100% which works when the columns are stacked but when they aren't it is not even with the column on the right. @adel xx

Comment: check edited post ! this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Remove height and add min-height

```
  .left {
  min-height: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your topic, I agree with Chris, if we could have more info it'd be easier to know how to help.
you can also use something like this in your html file, two pics with different sizes and to use a specific pic for every page size.

```
<picture id="pic">
<source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="image.jpg">
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="same pic bigger size" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```